# Is there anyway to use the index in python numpy vectorize functions?

Tags: python, numpy, iterable

The below example illustrates my problem:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> l = lambda i, value: i*v
>>> y = np.vectorize(l)
>>> y(range(10))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2755, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2825, in _vectorize_call
    ufunc, otypes = self._get_ufunc_and_otypes(func=func, args=args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2785, in _get_ufunc_and_otypes
    outputs = func(*inputs)
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
>>> y(enumerate(range(10)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2755, in __call__
    return self._vectorize_call(func=func, args=vargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2825, in _vectorize_call
    ufunc, otypes = self._get_ufunc_and_otypes(func=func, args=args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 2785, in _get_ufunc_and_otypes
    outputs = func(*inputs)
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
```

Is there anything like `fromiter` that supports this, but is faster with large inputs, like vectorize?

Comment: Is it intentional or a typo that `v` and `value` are distinct in the 2nd line? But independently of that, if you define `l` and `y` as a two-argument functions, why do you call `y` with one?

Comment: Why use `vectorize` on such a simple function? `l ` takes 2 arguments, `y` does as well, one as the source of scalar `i`, the other as scalar `value`

Comment: Did you read the `notes` from `np.vectorize`?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo @tif

Comment: "Why use vectorize on such a simple function?" the function is not actually simple, this function is for the purpose of demonstration

Answer (score 1):

`np.vectorize` is just a loop, applying a function to each value in an iterable. Given an iterable, it should be no more efficient than applying a function to each item sequentially via `map` + `enumerate`. You can then feed the `map` object to `np.fromiter`:

```
var = range(10)
indexed = enumerate(var)

def foo(x):
    idx, val = x
    return idx * val

res = np.fromiter(map(foo, indexed), dtype=int)

print(res)

[ 0  1  4  9 16 25 36 49 64 81]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take help of  `itertools.count`:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import count

i = count(-1)
l = lambda value: next(i) * value
y = np.vectorize(l)

print(y(range(10)))
# [ 0  1  4  9 16 25 36 49 64 81]
```

Comment: This won't work generically, e.g. with a generator, try `y((i for i in range(10)))`.